# How do I execute sudo subcommand in background

Tags: bash

I have a script that should run something like this:

```
sudo command &
othercommand
```

I need the password prompt for sudo to finish before othercommand is run, but the above setup runs *`sudo`* in the background rather than `command`

IE, bash is doing: `(sudo command) &` while I'd like `sudo (command &)`

I would use `sudo -b` but this makes `command` detatch from the terminal and makes it hard to stop since `^C` and `jobs` won't effect it.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think all you need is to make it `sudo command && othercommand`

Comment: `command` needs to be running as root in the background at the same time as `othercommand`, and be able to stop it easily in the same terminal (IE via `fg` `^C`)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1917089) topic could help a little.
I think you might try to do something like `sudo echo 'hi' && (sudo command othercommand) &` because second sudo would not ask for password. Kind of dirty workaround. :))

Comment: Yeah, `sudo true && sudo command &` works but for some reason I still can't stop `command` from the terminal afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to stop the background process when the script exits with for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> you could use a trap:

```
trap 'kill $pids' EXIT
[...]
sudo command & pids="${pids+$pids }$!"
[...]
othercommand
[...]
wait
```

This script will only exit once the `sudo` command is finished *or* it receives a terminating signal, at which point it will kill the `sudo` command before exiting.